# what does $ and * means in PCRE (Regular Expression)?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

i am using a Regular Expression that validates an email address here is the regular expression i am using.

```
preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/", $email)
```

most of the above code are self explanatory like

a) ^ represents NOT.

b) the start of the string should be either  `_ a-z  0-9`

c) match the next character which starts with dot

d) now what does *@ means here, couldn't it be just @  which means the next character should be @

e) next again it will try and find dot, the first dot is optional and the second is compulsory.

f) in the end what does $ means?

Comment: `^` does not represent "NOT" in this case. It only does so inside of a character class (and then only if it's the first character): `[^abc`]`. Here it means "start of the string".

Comment: <nit-pick>Also, that expression is wrong. It should end with `(\.[a-z]{2,})$/`. Otherwise, you're ignoring the .areo, .coop, .info, .museum, .name, .local, or .localdomain TLDs, or any new gTLDs that come around. </nit-pick>

Comment: @Thomas... the pattern is far more wrong than just that.

Comment: Whilst I don't know your development platform, but "regex buddy" is a fantastic piece of software to help understand regular expressions under a windows environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your assumption a) is not true

`^` is the start of the string in this case. At the beginning of a character class its a NOT.

`[_a-z0-9-]+` will match any of the chars in `[]` one or more times (because of the `+`)

`(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*` then there is a dot the same pattern than before and the `*` means this complete part can be repeated 0 or more times

Then there has to be the character `@`

Then the part from before the `@` repeats

`(\.[a-z]{2,3})$` the string has to end (defined by the `$`) with a `.` and 2 or 3 lowercase letters

Comment: In this case, `^` may be the start of a line or the string. For `^` (outside a character class) to strictly require the start of the string, the `s` modifier (either `/s` or `(?s)`) must be used.

Comment: @eyelidlessness yes in this case its the start of the string. At the beginning of a character class its a `NOT`. The `m` (multiline) modifier changes the behavior of the `^` with this modifier it matches additionally the start of a row. The `s` (dotall) modifier makes the `.` matches new line characters.

Comment: I stand corrected. I had confused the `s` (dotall) affect on `.` with the `m` (multiline) affect on `^` and `$`. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2):

* means the preceding rule 0 or multiple times

while $ in this case means the end of the string

```
(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)* // these characters can appear 0 or multiple times

(\.[a-z]{2,3})$ // the string ends with 2 letters in lowercase alphabet
```

Answer (score 2):

lots of information about regexp can be found at http://www.regular-expression.info

For example: f) see § Anchor at http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html

Answer (score 1):

Since the existing answers didn't cover this...

Yes, `*` means "zero or more times", but it is also "greedy" by default, so it will match as many times as possible, even if part of the matched string would have caused the next part of the pattern to match. `*` can be made "lazy" (allowing the pattern to "backtrack" to allow further matches in the pattern) by appending a `?`: `*?`.